# Changing web application asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a web application for managing projecs, meeting etc in our company that is written in asp.net MVC . right now each department have their own copies. 5 department 5 copies. how can we make it as just one app and fix this?

Comment: I am not entirely sure about what you're asking. You want to have a single instance of the ASP.NET site running is that ir?

Comment: yes we dont want have 5 diffrent copies like this

Comment: Can you not just create a site in IIS and then add folders to it for each of those sites? But what I don't know is what you need all those copies, sure you applications is prepared, at the business level, to have more than one department no?

Comment: because we have diffrent department diffrent staff diffrent project and all use copies of this web app . we want to fix this

Comment: Each department have their own users, but the departments still belong to the same company as the users. Maybe you need to rewrite some parts of the Application and have entities such as Users->AssignedToDepartment->Department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by centralizing your database at a central location you can easly do it or by using microsoft sync framework you can easly sync data to one db to another

Answer (score 0):

I would create a central mvc project, setup separate areas for each department, the source for each area into the main project.

You can also use each project as an area as outlined here:

http://nileshhirapra.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-pluggable-application.html